# Choosing id pattern in Postgres Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am creating a `feed` Table that will have feeds of users, and other objects like groups, events etc. I'm planning to have the following fields

```
id: character varying, primary key, unique
userId: character varying references user(id)
groupId: character varying references group(id)
.
.
.
```

So far I have been using a 25 character varchar for ids like `2JA8yJwC2gI91KFtIVAyClQa7` for all the other tables.

For the feed table, to avoid round trips, I'm thinking of using ids like
`user:2JA8yJwC2gI91KFtIVAyClQa7` and `group:GfgcqyReGBCVQ4TEGFvrEJova`,

where `2JA8yJwC2gI91KFtIVAyClQa7` is the `userId` and `GfgcqyReGBCVQ4TEGFvrEJova` is the `groupId`

Is there any downside to the above pattern?

Comment: "*using a 25 character varchar*" - why not use a `uuid`? It's more efficient, faster and will save storage space. But adding semantics to an ID (like a prefix denoting to which table the ID "belongs") is terrible idea. And how would you even setup a foreign key if you store `user:XXX` when the users table only contains `XXX`?

Comment: Why not use Integer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Why not use a `uuid`?
I initially used ORM - Prisma(https://www.prisma.io) and I didn't have an option then to decide on my ids. It was auto-generated by Prisma. I later started creating my own ids but tried to stick to the pattern that was there in around 300+ tables that were already created by the ORM. 
<br/>
**foreign key**
This is a table with polymorphic associations. Hence the id is not referencing any table. Instead `userId`, `groupId` etc. reference other tables.
Ex: A row is

`id: user:2JA8yJwC2gI91KFtIVAyClQa7`
`userId: 2JA8yJwC2gI91KFtIVAyClQa7`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it ok to use`uuid` for ids in future tables while the older ones have ids in the form of `varchar`? Or will the inconsistency in the pattern of ids in different tables do more harm than good?